# Google custom search how run command php

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I have a robot, i run it by this command :

```
robot:test:google
```

and in this robot, i have a function execute :

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    echo "test";
}
```

In this function i try to run command google custom search api, and i needed to call this :

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

But i don't find how run this command in my function execute.